# "mount" does not list a filesystem type

Tags: filesystems, mount, osx, disk-usage

[macOS] I am attempting to find out the filesystem type so that I can specify the type in order to mount something; when I attempted to use "mount" to find out the filesystem type no type was listed.  Instead of seeing something such as "/dev/disk on / type ext3" it lists "dev/disk on / ".  How can I determine the filesystem type in order to mount something and is this a problem?

I was also unable to use df -T and df --print-type to check the filesystem type.

Comment: Please edit this question to include `df -T` and mount output.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to replicate:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
```

The filesystem is `hfs`.